# Etiquette of presenting a problem you have managed to solve yourself

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I'm new round these parts.  I spent today struggling mightily with an MS-Access/SQL problem, and had just finished typing out my question when I thought of *one more thing* I could try before posting to the board.  This last idea led me to find my answer, so I don't need help anymore.  Win!

But!  But I searched for information about my solution on the Web and didn't find anything within the first page of Google hits.  It's either an undocumented "feature" of MS-Access 2007, or I'm just pretty bad at searching.  Anyway, this made me wonder -- what is the etiquette of asking a question I have already answered?  I don't want to look like some schmuck who wants to be able to upvote myself, but I doubt I'm the only person who will run into this Access problem, and it seems like it might be a public service to document it somewhere.